# gunicorn: command not found Flask

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I have created a flask app and it is running fine locally using this command
`gunicorn --workers 2 -b :5000 wsgi:app`  
Now I'm trying to run the same application in docker and I'm getting `./gunicorn_starter.sh: line 3: gunicorn: command not found`.

my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user

COPY . .
RUN chmod +x gunicorn_starter.sh
CMD ["./gunicorn_starter.sh" ]
```

gunicorn_starter.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
source venv/bin/activate
gunicorn --workers 2 -b :5000 wsgi:app
```

wsgi.py:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

File structure:

```
flask_app
    >venv
    dockerfile
    gunicorn_starter.sh
    app.py
    wsgi.py
    requirements.txt
```

I do have gunicorn in requiremnets.txt file. 
I have tried following links: 
[gunicorn not found when running a docker container with venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763029/gunicorn-not-found-when-running-a-docker-container-with-venv) 
[Installed gunicorn but it is not in venv/bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545344/installed-gunicorn-but-it-is-not-in-venv-bin-folder) 
[Gunicorn throwing error - cannot find executable on $PATH (Docker/Nginx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928825/gunicorn-throwing-error-cannot-find-executable-on-path-docker-nginx)

I couldn't figure out why it is not working, please help Thanks.

Comment: @tdelaney I think they mean "flask"

Comment: Sagar, we need to see your traceback (see this for example, https://realpython.com/python-traceback/#what-is-a-python-traceback)

Comment: @JesseH.  - But that's why I'm asking... to find out. If this is a copy/paste of the error message, then its obviously a misspelling in a file not posted here.

Comment: Sorry Just update Flaks to Flask. @tdelaney it is a copy/paste of the error message showing after running docker image

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most significant issue in what you show is that you're trying to `COPY` your host's virtual environment in the `venv` directory into the Docker image, but virtual environments aren't portable across installations.  So if the non-standard `source` command succeeds (if `/bin/sh` is actually GNU bash) you could be trying to run `./venv/bin/gunicorn`, but that's connected to a Python installation that doesn't exist inside the container.

The first thing you should do is write a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) that includes the line

```
venv
```

That will keep your host-based virtual environment out of the image build.  This avoids problems where the Python doesn't match (maybe it's not even the same OS) and also will make the `docker build` sequence run significantly faster.

The Docker image is isolated from other Python installations by virtue of being in Docker, so you don't need a virtual environment here.  One standard approach is to install packages into the "system" Python, but inside the isolated image.  This means you don't need to "activate" anything and you can dispense with the shell-script wrapper as well.

A simplified Dockerfile could look like:

```sh
FROM python:3.5

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./              # can skip second filename
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt  # without --user

COPY . .

CMD gunicorn --workers 2 -b :5000 wsgi:app  # without shell-script wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks @David, I made above changes and also change python:3.5 to python:3.7. Surprisingly it is working now